# How to make command that takes 2 argumetns

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, discord, discord.py

So, I`m making a discord bot that takes few commands one of them is

```
/watch
```

after that command user will type their address (blockchain)

```
/watch 0xAD488499b897a9667395526C39d0f3314A0f3FE9
```

I don't know how to make 2 variables in a message to get if watch to get the address
after the bot received to address it will save it in to text file with the user and every 30 sec it will check if it's mining (if it's not that means you need to reactivate it will alert the user that used the watch with that address)
Checking will be done with idena API
`https://api.idena.io/api/swagger/index.html`
it will check for `Online Miner status by the address`

Comment: It's the first things in the introduction.. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński its not working

Comment: ```import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)```

Comment: "its not working" -- *why*??

Comment: fixed somehow found some old code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program may help you according to your question

```
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@bot.command(name="test")
async def _test(ctx, first, second):
    # first variable takes first argument
    # second variable takes second argument
    # Your programming logic goes here...

bot.run(os.environ["TOKEN"]) # your bot token here
```